# How to discover common information blocks from multiple web pages of a same website?

Tags: machine-learning, web-crawler

It is a pattern recognition task in web crawler. The traditional crawler gets the data of the whole page. If there is any way to make the crawler a litter intelligence, like just to identify and capture the the information part.

Answer (score 1):

It is a research problem called **wrapper induction** or **web data extraction**. I don't know any library for this, but there are a lot of research papers (see below the list of good ones IMHO) and some research projects like [DIADEM](http://diadem.cs.ox.ac.uk/) (their site contains list of publications as well).

- Muslea, Ion, Steven Minton, and Craig A. Knoblock. “[Hierarchical
  Wrapper Induction for Semistructured Information Sources](http://www.ai.sri.com/~muslea/PS/jaamas-2k.pdf).” Autonomous
  Agents and Multi-Agent Systems 4, no. 1–2 (2001): 93–114.
- Dalvi, Nilesh, Ravi Kumar, and Mohamed Soliman. “[Automatic Wrappers for
  Large Scale Web Extraction.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.2406)” Proceedings of the VLDB Endowment 4, no.
  4 (2011): 219–230.
- Dalvi, Nilesh, Ashwin Machanavajjhala, and Bo Pang. “An Analysis of
  Structured Data on the Web.” Proceedings of the VLDB Endowment 5, no.
  7 (2012): 680–691.
- Gentile, Anna Lisa, Ziqi Zhang, Isabelle Augenstein, and Fabio
  Ciravegna. “[Unsupervised Wrapper Induction Using Linked Data](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.6406).” In
  Proceedings of the Seventh International Conference on Knowledge
  Capture, 41–48, 2013.
- Weninger, Tim, and Jiawei Han. “Exploring Structure and Content on
  the Web: Extraction and Integration of the Semi-Structured Web.” In
  Proceedings of the Sixth ACM International Conference on Web Search
  and Data Mining, 779–780, 2013.
  http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2433499.